# WebdriverIO - Close browser and open another

Tags: javascript, node.js, selenium-webdriver, webdriver-io

I am trying to test a scenario in my application where I need to close the browser and session and start a new browser and session to test the previously entered data is recalled successfully when I pass a set of launch parameters that will recall the data.  Although I am having issues with closing the first browser.

When I try `browser.close()` I get the error - `Error: no such session`

When I try `browser.end()` I get the error - `Error: Don't end the session manually. This will be done automatically.`

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Try "browser.quit()" . Hope this works!!

Answer (score 0):

You should use `browser.deleteSession()`. You can refer this https://webdriver.io/docs/api/webdriver#usage-1.

Comment: Thanks @Hirak. What to do after you have deleted the session ? The "new session" method is enough to bring it back up ?

Comment: For new browser sessions. I will recommend you use `remote`. Where you will get the browser object for the new session and you can easily use other webdriver api with it ```import { remote } from "webdriverio";
 const newBrowser = await remote({ capabilities: configuration });
    await newBrowser.url(url);``` You can refer here https://webdriver.io/docs/api/modules/#remoteoptions-modifier